# How can I edit the body of my Pebble.js UI.Card?

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I have created a card and shown it already. Now I want to change some text on it while it's in view. Can I just do something like `card.body = "blah blah"`? How do I update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write:

```
card.body("my new body");
```

This syntax works to change any property on all Pebble.js Windows and Elements.

Comment: Thanks! Is there, by any chance to set the font or at least the size of these text elements or can I only do that in dynamic/custom Windows?

Comment: You can only set the font if you are using a `UI.Window` and a `UI.Text` element.